# How could I figure out $ENV of trac?

Tags: trac

I install trac by bitnami on win7_64 and setup a project when the dialog box ask me.
When I create a new repository, I want to sync with it and I type
"trac-admin $ENV repository resync "libs_and_apps"

error message
"Error: No Trac environment found at C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack\$ENV
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\Program Files\BitNami Trac Stack\$EN
V\VERSION'"

I try to figure out the correct answer of $ENV, google tell me it is the path of your project
but I don't know where could I find the path of the project.

Comment: I find out a possible answer
"C:\Users\xxx\BitNami Trac Stack projects\Project"

but command window of trac would parse the path as
" C:\Users\xxx\BitNami"

this is my input
"trac-admin C:\\Users\\xxx\\BitNami Trac Stack projects\\Project repository resync "libs_and_apps" "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: Use quotes to tell the full path.

Spaces in a file patch are evil, best to avoid them, as you see here.

Comment: That was one of the big reasons why I ditched Bitnami's pre-canned Trac stack.  It was a good product overall, but it placed a lot of key components in directories with spaces in the name and writing scripts for that environment was a major headache.  A very unfortunate design decision.

Comment: I've just installed Bitnami's TracStack and there is an option during installation to change default dirs and that's exactly what I did and everything is working fine.